# React Native prettier eslint configuration. react-native-community config

Tags: react-native

I am new to React Native and will be installing Prettier and Eslint. I see that React Native come default with React Native react-native-community config. I like to know if airbnb is suitable from React Native should I continue to use the default config by React Native

Comment: Is there a specific reason you don't want to use the provided `react-native-community` config?

Comment: VScode stop showing my code errors from the rules set in eslint so I uninstalled eslint then I reinstalled it. While doing so I discover airbnb. This make me wonder if I should use react-native-community config or airbnb.

Comment: I would recommend using the default because it is already configured.